# GWT @source annoation how to read from war folder?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

May i know does @Source annotation only allow read file from src/package/client/* folder?  can it read from /war/ folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Source` *reads* from the classpath at **compile** time.

If you want/need to load resources that you don't want compiled into your JS, then use `ScriptInjector` or similar (`RequestBuilder`+`StyleInjector` or just dynamically adding a `LinkElement` to the DOM). If you want the ease of use of, say, `ImageResource` or `CssResource`, you could hand-write implementations rather than rely on the GWT generator. For `CssResource`, you could also simply use a dummy CSS stylesheet declaring all your classes as `@external` (and then injecting the CSS using either `StyleInjector` or a dynamic `LinkElement`).